# Why does the "id" command in Linux show the same group twice?

Tags: linux, permissions, docker, alpine-linux

For some reason as I was exploring Linux users and groups, the `id` command on a user I created in an [Alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine) container gives the following:

```
# id botmyaccount
uid=10001(botmyaccount) gid=10001(botmyaccount) groups=10001(botmyaccount),10001(botmyaccount)
```

which is confusing to me because it seems there is a duplicate of the `botmyaccount` (same name as the created user) group in the groups list. What's going on? Is it something involving supplementary vs primary groups of a user, though I thought that distinction was already made between the "gid" and "groups" lists?

The `botmyaccount` group only appears in a single entry within `/etc/group/`. This is all after running:

```
addgroup botmyaccount -g 10001
adduser botmyaccount -u 10001 -G botmyaccount
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because you used `-G` (instead of `-g`), which adds `botmyaccount` to the list of supplementary groups of the user (instead of setting that as its primary group).

Since `-g botmyaccount` is implied (see the man page of `adduser` for further details) and `groups=` list both the primary group and the supplementary groups of the user, you see two `botmyaccount`.

Answer (score -1):

Internally, `id` calls the Gnulib function [`mgetgroups`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=gnulib.git;a=blob;f=lib/mgetgroups.c;h=8570c910ced713f80aab2d103ad590f2bf513ca1;hb=HEAD). Its documentation says:

> If GID is not -1, store it first.

The actual magic happens in yet another function.

So this is actually well-defined behavior, even if not documented on the `id` man page.